# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'extend')

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, vuejs3, vuetifyjs3

I am trying to include the Vuetify library in an existing Vue 3 project, but I am having some problems. Here is the error message that appeared after compiling my project:

> vuetify.js?ce5b:42021 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'extend')
> ...

main.js:

```
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'

const app = createApp(App)
app.use(Vuetify)
app.mount('#app')
```

All imports of the Vuetify correspond to the official documentation.
Are these problems due to the version of my Vue project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[For Vue3 you need to install `vuetify@^3.0.1`](https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/installation/)

import it

```
import 'vuetify/styles'
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'
```

Then create it

```
const vuetify = createVuetify()
```

and then use it

```
app.use(vuetify)
```

Comment: Okay, thank you. But now I am faced with these errors after compilation `./node_modules/vuetify/dist/vuetify.js 902:28
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (902:28)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|   const DefaultsSymbol = Symbol.for('vuetify:defaults');
|   function createDefaults(options) {
>     return vue.ref(options ?? {});
|   }
|   function useDefaults() {`

Comment: @existentia hey mate, are you using Vue CLI or Vite? Please read instructions on link from my answer :)